# AngularJS http post not working with node server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have this code in my node backend server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And this is the api i.e. i want to call:

```
router.post('/update/:_id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("req.body:" + req.body);
}
```

This is my post request through angular 1:

```
var data = {something: "something"}
var url = 'http://localhost:8081/update/5982168b399ccf32ad75ce2e';

$http({
    withCredentials: false,
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: data
})
.then(function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        console.log("Post Data Submitted Successfully!");
    }
}, function (response) {
    console.log("Error status: " + response.status)
});
```

I am using Angular 1.6.1 version.

I have tried everything and looked through countless posts but none helped me. I can see the body going through. But i got undefined `req.body` in the node side backend.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Change content type to application/json

Comment: Show you app.js (where you calling `app.use` and routes).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Already tried the change to application/json and did not work.

Comment: The routes are ok. I can see it going to the api. I can see the log, it just says undefined instead of having something inside.

Comment: Make up your mind which body parser you want to use. Try using json parser and get rid of `headers: {'Content-Type'...`

Answer (score 3):

it could be the

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

your data is in JSON format, not x-www-form-urlencoded

```
{something: "something"}
```

you could try this

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

by default you send JSON data in $http POST, so you may not need the header
just take it out and try

===============================================================

also, your data may not be in valid format
JS does not know what something is, it's not a variable right?
you have to make it a string, even if its the key of a `{ "key": "value" }` pair
you could try this if above doesn't work

```
{
    "something": "something"
}
```

to verify your JSON
https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the data, and change the content type as was already said:

```
var data = {something: "something"}
var url = 'http://localhost:8081/update/5982168b399ccf32ad75ce2e';

$http({
    withCredentials: false,
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

You should in addition make sure that you can make a POST to that url using Postman and that the body is received to discart a problem in the server. On a side note, consider using Angular Resource.

Comment: $http does this by default internally